# PHP .htaccess Rewrite search term

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I must to rewrite my search term using .htaccess and instead pass the correct action to my form.

```
<form method="GET" action="/search/">
  <input type="text" name="src"/>
  <button>Search</button> 
</form>
```

I'm using this rule to rewrite the search URL:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ views/search.php?src=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

So I must to pass the `$src` variable to serve in the MySQL query

When i reach the page www.domain.com/search I got an error of undefinied index even if I append `?src=xxx`

Here is result page code (some parts are cut):

```
$term = $_GET['src'];

if(isset($term) !== NULL)
    {  
    $resultsrc = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '" . $term . "' OR brand LIKE '" . $term . "' LIMIT 0 , 30");
}
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_all($resulsrc))
   { 
 [... etc ... ]
  }
}
```

Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: What is the URL you're seeing in browser when you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regex capture group to capture the part after /search in url and then use it in the target url as $1

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$ views/search.php?src=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite

- /search/foo

to

- /views/search.php?src=foo

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i got the result expected but have the same issue `Undefined index: src ...` and instead i'd love the url appear as www.foo.bar/search/term, if is possible

Comment: @Andreaem The rule is ok, May be there is something wrong with your php. The rule internally redirects /search/term to search.php without changing the url in browser

Comment: I'm sure there is something wrong un my code, but I can't see where